# Python Pandas - Identifying the index of first matching value in a Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

So far I am getting the index of first matching record for a particular value in the Python data frame column. I get it using the code below :

```
df1.loc[df1.Column1 == 'word1'].index.tolist()[0]
```

Suppose if 'word1' is present four times in the data frame for example in the index positions : 3, 7, 9, 14, the above command will return me the answer as **3**

Now I need to check the same with multiple values for the column and the output should be the first matching index of any of those values.

I tried with few options as shown below but in vain.

```
df1.loc[df1.Column1 == 'word1'|'word2'].index.tolist()[0]
df1.loc[df1.Column1 == 'word1','word2'].index.tolist()[0]
df1.loc[df1.Column1 == 'word1' or 'word2'].index.tolist()[0]
```

Any idea on how to check for multiple values here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for condition:

```
df1.loc[df1.Column1.isin(['word1','word2'])].index.tolist()[0]
```

Simplier solution with [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for get index of first max value, because `True`s are handle like `1`s:

```
print (df1.Column1.isin(['word1','word2']))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
Name: Column1, dtype: bool

df1.Column1.isin(['word1','word2']).idxmax()
```

Or with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
np.where(df1.Column1.isin(['word1','word2']))[0][0]
```

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Column1':['s','g','h','word2','d','f','word1','d']})

a = df1.Column1.isin(['word1','word2']).idxmax()
print (a)
3
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But can you please shed more light on idxmax. By its name I assume there must be something called idxmin as well.

Comment: Yes, `df1.Column1.isin(['word1','word2']).idxmin()` return first `False` index, test it by `df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Column1':['word2','g','h','word2','d','f','word1','d']})`